# Using the C# Compler to compile Custom Channels DLL for Event Viewer rc file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-viewer

I'm attempting to create a custom events DLL for Event Viewer on Windows 10 by using the directions in the following [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/russellt/2016/05/18/creating-custom-windows-event-forwarding-logs/) and corresponding [git repo](https://github.com/palantir/windows-event-forwarding).  When I get to the step where we compile the custom `.dll` for the channels, I get the following error about my resource file which in the blog post is a `.res` file, but my resulting resource file ended up being a `.rc` file.

```
C:\Users\ajleer\someplace\Projects\wef_test\windows-event-forwarding>"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /win32res:"C:\Users\ajleer\someplace\Projects\wef_test\windows-event-forwarding\ProcessExplorerChannels.rc" /unsafe /target:library /out:"C:\Users\ajleer\someplace\Projects\wef_test\windows-event-forwarding\windows-event-channels\ProcessExplorerChannels.dll" "C:\Users\ajleer\someplace\Projects\wef_test\windows-event-forwarding\ProcessExplorerChannels.cs"
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3190.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

error CS1583: 'c:\Users\ajleer\someplace\Projects\wef_test\windows-event-forwarding\ProcessExplorerChannels.rc' is not a valid Win32 resource file
```

I'm not really sure what to do with this.  Is it because I'm using an old version of the C# Compiler to run it?

Comment: According to the screenshots on that blog you should have both a .res and a .rc file and your win32res: parameter should point at the .res file.

Comment: The C# compiler doesn't know anything about an .rc file, it needs a .res file.  Run rc.exe to generate it, as shown in the blog post.

Comment: Hey close vote, what is your issue with this?